# I got virus on my computer

Tags: windows-7, virus

I got virus on my computer. This is a list of executables of the virus:

```
Name              |Size  |Description
------------------+------+------------- 
B06A.exe          |162   |B06A
D3F2.exe          |217414|wYtRBdGyks
E3DA.exe          |357190|TWunHOlqmZ
NTDETECT.COM      |177152|Mail.Ru Агент
ScreenSaverPro.scr|177152|Mail.Ru Агент
temp.bin          |177152|  (none)
ViewFiles.cmd     |177152|Mail.Ru Агент
Zafgff.exe        |177152|Mail.Ru Агент
```

I have found the virus had done the following, but I haven't find actual damage yet:

1. Folders in my USB disk became hidden and system. Links with the same name with those folders were spawned. Clicking those links cause virus to run.
2. Registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` was set to run this virus when I login.

**Do anyone know this virus? What does it actually do? Or is it a new one? How can I report it?**

Comment: Report Viruses to Symantec: http://www.symantec.com/security_response/submitsamples.jsp

Comment: Well `ScreenSaverPro.scr` seems to be [this guy](http://about-threats.trendmicro.com/Malware.aspx?id=54609&name=WORM_DORKBOT.ME&language=au)

Answer (score 0):

A site I use a lot for testing viruses and such is http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/ They have a community where you can submit the virus and people can look into it.